# How can I manually reset the default video settings in HL1?

Tags: technical-issues, half-life

I changed the video settings to the maximum resolution that the game supports and widescreen.

I wanted to change back but now only a small part of the game is available on the screen to I can't get to where I can change the settings.

I have re-installed and tried both the "-safe" and "-autoconfig" set launch options but they didn't do anything.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Possibly useful: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Command_Line_Options#Goldsource_Games

Comment: Delete the config file?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie the .cfg file? I deleted it but it just creates a new one when I play it and it doesn't change the settings

Comment: Is this *Half Life* or is this *Half Life: Source*?

Comment: @Kecoey Hm, I'm having a hard time finding the file where resolution is stored. It doesn't appear to be any of the (multiple) config files that HL:S uses. But using 3ventic's link, I've figured out another way to fix this, so I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is *Half Life: Source*, then you can start the game with this command line option in order to have it re-autodetect your screen and use the default size it first started with:

```
-autoconfig
```

This will *not* fix your config file, but it will ignore the current (bad) config files, allowing you to fix your resolution settings, close the game, then run the game without the `-autoconfig` option to use your newly-chosen resolution.

You can add command line options to a game from within Steam by right-clicking the game in your Library, choosing **Properties**, clicking **Set Launch Options**, then pasting in `-autoconfig` (or whatever command line option you're adding).

---

If this is *Half Life* (the original), then you can start the game using the `-w` and `-h` command line options to tell it to start up with a different resolution. For example:

```
hl.exe -w 800 -h 600
```

Will start the game up in 800x600 (4:3 resolution), and will allow you to fix your graphics settings to that next time you start the game without the `-w` and `-h` options, it'll use your new resolution settings.

---

Reference source: [Command Line Options article](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Command_Line_Options) at the Valve Developer Community site ([thanks to 3ventic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/138555/how-can-i-reset-the-default-video-settings-in-hl1#comment189129_138555))

Comment: @Kecoey Worked? Excellent!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is the Steam version of HL1 you can

1. Go to Properties by right clicking on the game in your library
2. Select Set Launch Options
3. Enter `-window -noborder -width [native width of monitor] -height [native height of monitor]` without the brackets

This fixed the problem for me